# spring security does not authenticate

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am writing a simple web app using spring security 3.2.0 and spring framework 4.x. I can see the username/pass are coming through in the custom auth provider but the actual authentication is not done; that is, when entering a wrong password i am still taken to the post login url /dashboard...

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring-security-config.xml
            </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>frontController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>frontController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

spring-security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">  
    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard*" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <form-login login-page='/login' default-target-url='/dashboard'
            always-use-default-target='true' authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/" />

    </http>    
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />

    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Custom auth provider does not do anything except delegating to user service:

```
 public class AuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {
     //nothing here
 }
```

and the user service gets the user details by id and is injected into the auth provider above:

```
public class UserLoginService implements UserDetailsService{

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserDetail ud = new UserDetail();
    User u = new User();
    ud.setUser(u);
    u.setUsername("reza");
    u.setPassword("reza");
    u.setAccountNonExpired(true);
    u.setAccountNonLocked(true);
    u.setCredentialsNonExpired(true);
    u.setEnabled(true);
    u.setRole("ROLE_USER");
    return ud;
    }


public class UserDetail implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails {

    User user;
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(1);
         authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
        return authList;
    }
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {

        return user.getPassword();
    }
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return user.isAccountNonExpired();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return user.isAccountNonLocked();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return user.isCredentialsNonExpired();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.isEnabled();
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to add the code for your authentication provider and UserDetailsService.

Comment: post your full UserLoginService

Comment: I over wrote the authenticate method on the auth provider and called super.authenticate() and it worked. But to me this step seems unnecessary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overwrote the authenticate method on the auth provider and called super.authenticate() and it worked.